# Cannot add user+role record in aspnet Identity

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

- Web Forms project / VB / ASP 4.5.2 / VS2015
- EntityFramework 6.1.3 / Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.1
- Other packages in NuGet all show current versions

I have a webapp using the VS template which includes pages that create users etc. I have created users and they can/can not access folders according to the web.config in the various folders.

Now I need to add roles and attach roles to users.

I can create roles using

```
 Dim createRole As String = RoleTextBox.Text
        Dim RoleManager = New RoleManager(Of IdentityRole)(New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(New ApplicationDbContext()))
        Try
            If RoleManager.RoleExists(createRole) Then
                Msg.Text = "Role '" & Server.HtmlEncode(createRole) & "' already exists. Please specify a different role name."
                Return
            End If

            RoleManager.Create(New IdentityRole(createRole))
```

etc

Next I need to attach roles to users, for which I have got:

```
Public Class admin_superadmin
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim UserManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)(New IdentityDbContext()))
        UserManager.AddToRole(DropDownList5.SelectedValue, DropDownList6.SelectedValue)
        Label1.Text = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text + " Was added to the " + DropDownList6.SelectedValue + " Role."
    End Sub
```

However when run this fails at the line usermanager.addtorole with the message:
System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.

The DB tables were created by the app.  In table AspNetUserRoles are fields UserID, RoleID.

Much appreciated if someone could help identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to this as a front-end designer wanting to authenticate users but having never used Identity or MVC, in the end I figured it out and these would have been a ten minute way to get a simple web app up and running with authentication and roles, using a remote db:

File > New Project > Web > ASP.NET web application > Web forms

In web.config, change the DefaultConnection to point to my existing remote MSSQL db

In the solution explorer Account > Register.aspx > View in Browser

in the browser, register a new User: in the remote database, all needed authentication tables are set up for me and I can now add and modify users from the VS template project pages in the Account folder. But I cannot use Roles yet.

Project > Add New Item > VB (for me) > Data > ADO.NET Entity Data model > EF Designer from database > make it refer to DefaultConnection > tick all tables

I can now create an admin folder and in it a page with a few controls and the code 
UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, ) will succeed and not give the error reported in my original question.

Hope these steps might help another beginner.